# Wordpress - Send two Messages one for Post Author and one for all Users when the Post is Published

Tags: php, wordpress, message, author

Finally i did it, I'm using "[Front-End PM](https://sa.wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/)" plugin, So far I created this function to send message for the post Author when he/she post is published.

But how can i create two messages one for the post author and one for all users, for notice all of them about the new published post.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
    return;
    $message = [];

    $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; // Post author ID. 
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
    $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.', $name, $title );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'This is an automatic message, to let you know your post is published, and qualified for our quality standard!' );
    $override = array('post_author' => 1);//change with message sender id  


    // Send message
    fep_send_message( $message, $override );      
}
```

Here is the fep_send_message function, I want to make the two message in one function..this can happen?

```
function fep_send_message( $message = null, $override = array() ) {
    if ( null === $message ) {
        $message = $_POST;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $message['fep_parent_id'] ) ) {
        $message['post_parent'] = absint( $message['fep_parent_id'] );
        $message['post_status'] = fep_get_option( 'reply_post_status', 'publish' );
        $message['message_title'] = __( 'RE:', 'front-end-pm' ). ' ' . wp_slash( fep_get_message_field( 'mgs_title', $message['post_parent'] ) );
        $message['message_to_id'] = fep_get_participants( $message['post_parent'], true );
    } else {
        $message['post_status'] = fep_get_option( 'parent_post_status','publish' );
        $message['post_parent'] = 0;
    }
    $message = apply_filters( 'fep_filter_message_before_send', $message );
    if ( empty( $message['message_title'] ) || empty( $message['message_content'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Create post array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $message['message_title'],
        'post_content'  => $message['message_content'],
        'post_status'   => $message['post_status'],
        'post_parent'   => $message['post_parent'],
        'post_type'     => 'message',
        'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'mgs_created'   => current_time( 'mysql', true ),
    );

    if ( $override && is_array( $override ) ) {
        $post = wp_parse_args( $override, $post );
    }
    if( ! $post['post_parent'] && 'threaded' === fep_get_message_view() ){
        $post['mgs_last_reply_by

    '] = $post['post_author'];
            $post['mgs_last_reply_excerpt'] = fep_get_the_excerpt_from_content( 100, $post['post_content'] );
            $post['mgs_last_reply_time'] = $post['mgs_created'];
        }

        $post = apply_filters( 'fep_filter_message_after_override', $post, $message );

        foreach( $post as $k => $v ){
            if( 0 === strpos( $k, 'post_') ){
                $post[ str_replace( 'post_', 'mgs_', $k ) ] = $v;
                unset( $post[ $k ] );
            }
        }
        $post = wp_unslash( $post );

        $new_message = new FEP_Message;
        $message_id = $new_message->insert( $post );
        // Insert the message into the database
        if ( ! $message_id  ) {
            return false;
        }
        /*
        $inserted_message = FEP_Message::get_instance( $message_id );
        if( ! $inserted_message ){
            return false;
        }
        */
        if( ! empty( $message['message_to_id'] ) ){
            $message['message_to_id'] = (array) $message['message_to_id'];
            $message['message_to_id'][] = $new_message->mgs_author;
            $new_message->insert_participants( $message['message_to_id'] );
        }
        do_action( 'fep_action_message_after_send', $message_id, $message, $new_message );

        fep_status_change( 'new', $new_message );

        return $message_id;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share this function "fep_send_message"

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar, Sorry for late reply, I updated my question.

Comment: Any help please @PraveenKumar.

Comment: Can you please let me know your flow? If any admin author  (in admin side) add post and public than send email to admin (author) and user (User subscription) send email right? @AdhamMohamed

Comment: Hello, The first snippet above working perfectly without any problems! I just need to send two types of msg when any post is published one for post author and one for all registered users they all in (role contributors), Sorry I'm newbie with wp and I don't know how can i explain it well.

Comment: Hello, you need to send 2 type message to the same user (role contributors)?

Comment: or  Send two Messages one for Post Author (Current Author) and one for all Users when the Post is Published right?

Comment: Yes right, Send two Messages one for Post Author (Current Author) and one for all Users when the Post is Published.

Comment: the first function above send only to Post Author, So i need to send for all Users also, something like "hey new post is published by(...) take a look ( permalink ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code for [Front End PM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/) plugin. I updated some code in "send_message_to_contributor" as "fep_send_message".

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    if ( ! function_exists( 'fep_send_message' ) )
    return;
    $message = [];

    $message['message_to_id'] = $post->post_author; // Post author ID. 
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); 
    $message['message_title'] = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message['message_content'] = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.', $name, $title );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $message['message_content'] .= sprintf( 'This is an automatic message, to let you know your post is published, and qualified for our quality standard!' );
    $override = array('post_author' => 1);//change with message sender id 

    // Send message
    send_message_to_contributor( $name, $title );      
}


function send_message_to_contributor( $message = null, $override = array() ) {

    $blogusers = get_users();

    if ( null === $message ) {
        $message = $_POST;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $message['fep_parent_id'] ) ) {
        $message['post_parent'] = absint( $message['fep_parent_id'] );
        $message['post_status'] = fep_get_option( 'reply_post_status', 'publish' );
        $message['message_title'] = __( 'RE:', 'front-end-pm' ). ' ' . wp_slash( fep_get_message_field( 'mgs_title', $message['post_parent'] ) );
        $message['message_to_id'] = fep_get_participants( $message['post_parent'], true );
    } else {
        $message['post_status'] = fep_get_option( 'parent_post_status','publish' );
        $message['post_parent'] = 0;
    }
    $message = apply_filters( 'fep_filter_message_before_send', $message );
    if ( empty( $message['message_title'] ) || empty( $message['message_content'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Create post array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $message['message_title'],
        'post_content'  => $message['message_content'],
        'post_status'   => $message['post_status'],
        'post_parent'   => $message['post_parent'],
        'post_type'     => 'message',
        'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'mgs_created'   => current_time( 'mysql', true ),
    );

    if ( $override && is_array( $override ) ) {
        $post = wp_parse_args( $override, $post );
    }
    if( ! $post['post_parent'] && 'threaded' === fep_get_message_view() ){
        $post['mgs_last_reply_by'] = $post['post_author'];
        $post['mgs_last_reply_excerpt'] = fep_get_the_excerpt_from_content( 100, $post['post_content'] );
        $post['mgs_last_reply_time'] = $post['mgs_created'];
    }

    $post = apply_filters( 'fep_filter_message_after_override', $post, $message );

    foreach( $post as $k => $v ){
        if( 0 === strpos( $k, 'post_') ){
            $post[ str_replace( 'post_', 'mgs_', $k ) ] = $v;
            unset( $post[ $k ] );
        }
    }
    $post = wp_unslash( $post );

    $new_message = new FEP_Message;
    $message_id = $new_message->insert( $post );
    // Insert the message into the database
    if ( ! $message_id  ) {
        return false;
    }
    /*
    $inserted_message = FEP_Message::get_instance( $message_id );
    if( ! $inserted_message ){
        return false;
    }
    */
    /*if( ! empty( $message['message_to_id'] ) ){
        $message['message_to_id'] = (array) $message['message_to_id'];
        $message['message_to_id'][] = $new_message->mgs_author;
        $new_message->insert_participants( $message['message_to_id'] );
    }*/
    /*Update code here*/
    foreach ($blogusers as $key => $value) {
        $message['message_to_id'] = array();
        $message_user = $value->data->ID;
        if($message_user != $new_message->mgs_author){
            $message['message_to_id'][] = $message_user;//(array) $message['message_to_id'];
            $message['message_to_id'][] = $new_message->mgs_author;
            $new_message->insert_participants( $message['message_to_id'] );
        }
    }
    /*End updated code*/
    do_action( 'fep_action_message_after_send', $message_id, $message, $new_message );

    fep_status_change( 'new', $new_message );

    return $message_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, but how can i override the plugin code to my child theme, every time the plugin owner makes updating so i'll adding your code manually after update!!

Comment: @AdhamMohamed - You can create some name folder (Plugin "front-end-pm") in theme Folder and copy (functions.php) that file in this Folder. If the plugin is updated then your code will not update.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. It will help you.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage', 10, 2 );

function fep_cus_user_publish_send_messaage( $ID, $post ){

    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $messaged = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $messaged .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = ''; 
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $messaged, $headers ); 


    // Send message
    send_message_to_contributor( $name, $title );      
}


function send_message_to_contributor($author_name, $post_title) {

    $blogusers = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'contributor' ] ] );

    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
        $user_name = $user->data->display_name;
        $email = $user->data->user_email;
        $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $user_name, $email );
        $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $post_title );
        $message = sprintf ('Hello, %s! New post is “%s” published.' . "\n\n", $user_name, $post_title );
        $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
        $headers[] = '';
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
}
```

If email is not sent then install this plugin and set up SMTP [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)